# How to access variable from an included page?

Tags: php

I'm using some "beginner" masterpage-like in PHP, and I connect to the database from one page, but want to access it from an included page as well. I define the database variable above the include call, so there shouldn't be any problem there.

Currently, when including the page and checking if the variable is set, it returns false. How can I accomplish such thing instead of re-connecting in every include?

### index.php

```
$db = new mysqli("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DB");
include 'page2.php';
```

### page2.php

```
if(isset($db))
    echo 'set';
else
    echo 'not set'; // this will be called
```

Comment: Add some minimal code that recreates the issue.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I added some example of what I'm trying to do. @Rasclatt

Comment: do you see any error?

Comment: No, the `$db` variable is just not set in page2.

Answer (score 2):

This should come like this

**index.php**

```
include 'page2.php';
if(isset($db))
    echo 'set';
else
    echo 'not set'; // this will be called
```

**page2.php**

```
$db = new mysqli("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DB");
```

[`Include` in php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: `index.php` is my masterpage and it creates the mysqli instance. I'm trying to access the instance from my included page, not the other way around.

Comment: you can use `page2` for store code. So that you can access all variables as usual

Comment: page2 is some page that gets built in the masterpage and has other functionalities than other pages. That's why I want to do all the database checks that relates page2 in its code and not in the masterpage. If I want to do this in the masterpage, I wouldn't make a masterpage.

Comment: To create `$db` in the masterpage (index.php) and access it from page2.php.

Comment: Noo !!. This is only correct way to use. Cz `$db` should paste in another file. So that you can use `$db`  in any of your page by using `include 'page2.php';`

Comment: So I can't pass a variable to an included page?

Comment: includes only allow to access data. Not to write. If we can write variable in include file it will be hacking of your site

Answer (score 0):

Update your page2.php like this. Hope your code will work fine now.

```
if(!($db->connect_error))
    echo 'connected';
else
    echo 'Not connected';
```

Comment: You're just making things up, man. If $db is not set, how will it have a `connect_error` property.

Comment: isset is used to check variable is set or not.  connect_error property is to output error string and if there are no error it returns null. Thats why if statement can check for error and output whether database is connected or not.

Comment: @OmerAviv that code is for page2. Since you have created an instance of `mysqli` class

Comment: I created it in index.php, and page2 doesn't have access to it.

Comment: what is your php version