# Viewing PHP variables of an Included file in the main PHP file

Tags: php

I have a PHP file "main.php" that has at the top the following statement:

```
include "config_file.php";
```

The config_file.php includes the settings of five simple variables. Is there a way to display or view these five variables in the main.php file? If not, is there a better way to define these variables outside the main.php file (in a config file) and yet see the variables in the main.php file? An example will help.

Thanks,
Menachem

Comment: What do you mean by `"see"`? As in use? Since you could just call them....`echo $variable_name`...

Comment: `echo` the variables e.g `<?php echo $variable;?>`

Comment: Make those variable Global variable and use it anywhere you like by including the file

Comment: I cannot echo them because the PHP file is executed when the page is not visible. I want to view the included file variable settings at the source level.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the variable of included file

just

```
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
include 'config_file.php';
if(isset($db))
    echo 'set';
else
    echo 'not set'; // this will be called
```

**config_file.php**

```
$db = new mysqli("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DB");
```

And **Possible duplicate of** [How to access variable from an included page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800760/how-to-access-variable-from-an-included-page)

**Edit 01**

**a.php**

```
$a = 'Abulla';
$b = 'Menachem';
```

**b.php**

you can just use

```
include 'a.php';
echo $a.' and '.$b;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. I cannot use a DB and I cannot echo them because the PHP file is executed when the page is not visible. I want to view the included file variable settings at the source level.

Answer (score 0):

Including the PHP file usually will give you access to all variables defined in this file. That means that you can simply use variables defined in `config_file.php` in your `main.php`.

Example:

Main.php:

```
 <?php
    include "config_file.php";
    // The code included below is example, you may do anything you want with variables
    $example_result = $a + $b;
print($example_result); // Just and example
    file_put_contents ("debug.txt" , $example_result); // Just an example
    // This should result in debug.txt contain $a + $b meaning that this file content should be "3"
```

config_file.php:

```
   <?php
 $a = 1;
 $b = 2;
```

This may slightly differ if one of your files is a PHP class. In this case please give us a notice.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that I wanted to view the "include" file variables in the source code was to improve the readability of the code.

I solved this problem by pasting the content of the "include" file into the main file as comments.